# Route tablet users to desktop web site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile

We have two different web sites for desktop and mobile versions. Desktop being hosted at the '*www.samplesite.com*' and mobile at '*m.samplesite.com*'. Currently, all the mobile devices (phones and tablets) are automatically redirected to mobile version of the site.

We want the tablet users to be redirected to desktop version of the site instead of the mobile version. How can we distinguish tablets from phones?

Appreciate your suggestions on how to detect tablets separately and routing it to desktop site.